# C segfault, not sure what's going down

Tags: c, formatting, format, segmentation-fault

I have the following code, and on line 68, I'm getting a format error.
`stack.c:68: warning: format ‘%e’ expects type ‘float *’, but argument 3 has type ‘double *’`

On the input `push 4`, it gets a segfault. Not sure if they're related. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define OFFSET '0'
#define DIM1 7
#define DIM2 5
#define RES_SIZE 1000

//typedef double double;

typedef struct {
  double *contents;
  int maxSize;
  int top;
} stackT;

void StackInit(stackT *stackP, int maxSize) {
    double *newContents;
    newContents = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double)*maxSize);
    if (newContents == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    stackP->contents = newContents;
    stackP->maxSize = maxSize;
    stackP->top = -1;
}

void StackDestroy(stackT *stackP) {
    free(stackP->contents);
    stackP->contents = NULL;
    stackP->maxSize = 0;
    stackP->top = -1;
}

int StackIsEmpty(stackT *stackP) { return stackP->top < 0; }

int StackIsFull(stackT *stackP) { return stackP->top >= stackP->maxSize-1; }

void StackPush(stackT *stackP, double element) {
    if(StackIsFull(stackP)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't push element: stack is full.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    stackP->contents[++stackP->top] = element;
}

double StackPop(stackT *stackP) {
    if(StackIsEmpty(stackP)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't pop element: stack is empty.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return stackP->contents[stackP->top--];
}

void StackShow(stackT *stackP) {
    int i;
    printf("[ ");
    for (i = 0; i < stackP->top - 1; i++) {
        printf("%e, ", stackP->contents[i]);
    }
    printf("%e ]\n", stackP->contents[stackP->top - 1]);
}

double shell(char* s1, double arg) {
    printf(">   ");
    scanf("%s %f%*c", s1, &arg);
    return arg;
}

int main() {
    //char cmds[DIM1][DIM2] = {{"push"}, {"pop"}, {"add"}, {"ifeq"}, {"jump"}, {"print"}, {"dup"}};
    stackT res;
    StackInit(&res, RES_SIZE);
    char cmd[DIM2]; double arg = 0;
    arg = shell(cmd, arg);
    if (StringEqual(cmd, "push")) {
        StackPush(&res, arg);
        StackShow(&res);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says. You cannot use a `double` variable with a `float` format specifier. Use "%lf". There's also an off-by-one error in `StackShow`, plus you ignore the fact that a stack may be empty.

Comment: I changed it to `%lf` on 68, segfault still there, what's wrong with `StackShow`?

Comment: Have you tried running the code in a debugger? It'll give you the answer right away...

Comment: The off-by-one error, that's exactly what's wrong. Your stack top is at stackP->top, not at stackP->top-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had a quick look on you code , I think after pushing the first element your stack top pointer is set to 0 .
Now in you StackShow() method you are accessing an invalid memory location from this line :

```
 printf("%e ]\n", stackP->contents[stackP->top - 1]); // accessing invalid location stackP->contents[-1]
```

This is an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) for the array contents .

Answer (score 1):

I just took a quick look..the last line in your stackShow() method seems to be the problem. Besides i think you should debug this yourself, a starting point would be to run through your program and see what the indices will be for 1 element.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: kakira and CodeBuzz are correct.  Your segfault is from `StackShow`.  The error I pointed out below will cause `arg` to be set incorrectly, but it won't cause your segfault.

---

Your compiler is telling you what the problem is.  Your `scanf` is expecting a pointer to a float, but your giving a pointer to a double.  On Linux, you would specify the double to scanf as `%lf`, but if your compiler needs a `%e`, then try using that.

You also have a problem because you're calling `shell` with the value of `arg` not its address.  You give the address to `arg` in the `scanf`, but all you're doing there is putting a value into a variable local to that subroutine.  You should be doing something more like:

```
void shell(char *s1, double *arg)
{
    scanf("%s %lf%*c", s1, arg);
}

main()
{
    ...
    double arg;
    shell(cmd, &arg);
}
```

This way, the `scanf` populates the `arg` you're passing it, and you don't need to also return the value.  If you'd rather continue to return the value separately, then don't pass it in, as it only confuses the issue.  E.g.:

```
double shell(char *s1, double *arg)
{
    double arg;
    scanf("%s %lf%*c", s1, &arg);
    return arg;
}

main()
{
    ...
    double arg;
    arg = shell(cmd);
}
```